# DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"

Tags: linux, perl, postgresql, dbi

Trying to set a value in PostgreSQL using Perl and DBI, and thus DBD::Pg.

I'm getting an odd error.

```
2013-05-23 19:02:36.641139500 updating status to 0
2013-05-23 19:02:36.641410500 DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
2013-05-23 19:02:36.641418500 LINE 1: UPDATE instances SET $1 = $2
2013-05-23 19:02:36.641423500                              ^ at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/Mitel/MslRest/mbg.pm line 161.
2013-05-23 19:02:36.642425500 [Thu May 23 19:02:36 2013] [error] DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
2013-05-23 19:02:36.642438500 LINE 1: UPDATE instances SET $1 = $2
2013-05-23 19:02:36.642443500                              ^ at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/Mitel/MslRest/mbg.pm line 161.
2013-05-23 19:02:36.642447500
```

The relevant code is

```
my $sql = "UPDATE instances SET ? = ?";
my $dbh = Mitel::tug::getdbh();
$dbh->begin_work;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
unless ($sth) {
    return $self->internal_error("prepare failed: " . $dbh->errstr);
}
foreach my $propname (sort keys %{ $raw_data }) {
    my $propval = $raw_data->{$propname};
    print STDERR "updating $propname to $propval\n";
    if (! $sth->execute($propname, $propval)) {
        $dbh->rollback;
        $sth->finish;
        return $self->internal_error("execute: " . $dbh->errstr);
    }
}
$dbh->commit;
$sth->finish;
```

So I'm trying to update "status" to 0, using the execute method to prevent sql injection, but I'm getting a syntax error for some reason.

Anyone run into this?

```
root@miketug2 ~]# perl -v

This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i386-linux-thread-multi

perl-DBD-Pg-2.15.1-4.el6_3.i686
postgresql84-server-8.4.14-1PGDG.rhel6.i686

root@miketug2 ~]# uname -a
Linux miketug2 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Wed Feb 6 00:31:03 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 9):

PostgreSQL prefers that you use numbered placeholders (`$1`, `$2`, ...) over the positional `?` placeholders so someone is translating your `?` placeholders to number placeholders; that's why your SQL:

```
UPDATE instances SET ? = ?
```

ends up as:

```
UPDATE instances SET $1 = $2
```

in the error message.

Now the real problem is that you can't use placeholders for identifiers (table names, column names, ...), you can only use placeholders for values. You can't say `SET ? = ?`, you have to supply the column name some other way, probably through string interpolation. This means that you have to move your `prepare` inside your loop to something like this:

```
foreach my $propname (sort keys %{ $raw_data }) {
    my $prop    = $dbh->quote_identifier($propname);
    my $propval = $raw_data->{$propname};
    my $sth     = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE instances SET $prop = ?");
    $sth->execute($propval);
    $sth->finish();
}
```

Your real code would, of course, include error handling. Note the use of [`quote_identifier`](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/DBD-Pg-2.19.3/Pg.pm#quote_identifier) to make the column name safe for interpolation. If you're going to end up with this simple `prepare`, `execute`, `finish` sequence then you might want to just use [`do`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#do) instead.

Comment: +1 for: _you can't use placeholders for identifiers (table names, column names, ...)_ ...thanks!